# Can Casablanca be used as a webserver to serve assets?

Tags: c++, web-services, rest, web, casablanca

Does Casablanca (Microsoft's C++ REST SDK) be used to serve web assets (html, images, js, css, etc)?

I built a REST server with Casablanca, and for the specific REST stuff it works great.  But how do I serve a full site?

Do I have to run nginx/apache in parallel to my REST server to serve assets, or build some simple file webserver with boost.asio, etc?

I am targeting an embedded system and thus want to keep a low resources demand, so ideally Casablanca it self could serve my assets as well as my routes.

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't want to do that with Casablanca. It's intended for use as a REST endpoint server. It's possible, but it makes more sense to use an instance of Apache/Tomcat to serve a website.

That being said, it is possible. You can give it a try by doing something like the following in your GET Handler:

```
void HandleGet( http_request Message) {
    utility::string_t body = 
        "<html><body>"
        "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"
        "</body></html>";
    Message.reply( status_codes::OK, body, L"text/html");
}
```